# SwiftUI drag and drop on moving/animating view/shape

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to implement drag and drop feature in SwiftUI. It seems when view is not animating the following code works fine. But when I am moving the view with offset then there is some issue with drag location and view like view location is not same as touch location and view shape is not same as original.

**Dragging without offset animation(animate = false) works fine:**

[image: Dragging without offset animation]

**Dragging with offset animation(animate = true):**

[image: Dragging with offset animation true]

Code Snippet:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dropDelegate = CircleDropDelegate()
    @State var animate = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Spacer()
        
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .offset(x: animate ? 100 : 0)
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .onDrag({
                    return NSItemProvider(object: "circle" as NSString)
                })
        
            Spacer()
        
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: 150)
                .onDrop(of: ["public.text"], delegate: dropDelegate)
        
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            animate = true
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.init(white: 0.7))
    }
}

class CircleDropDelegate: ObservableObject, DropDelegate {
    @Published var isEntered: Bool = false
    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        print("perform drop on box \(info)")
        return true
    }

    func dropEntered(info: DropInfo) {
        print("circle entered the box")
        isEntered = true
    }

    func dropExited(info: DropInfo) {
        print("circle exited the box")
        isEntered = false
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Offset does not change real view position, only rendering place. It is not clear the purpose of offset here.

Comment: I am changing the offset over time to move the circle left to right with animation.